# Re-Arranging the DataGrid View columns display

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

Im using ms access as a database for my system and i recently rearranged the columns. Problem is the datagrid view in my system does not display the new arrangement of the database.

How can i make the datagridview display the new arrangement of my database

Comment: Please show the code you have for setting up the datagridview. Usually you specify in the code what the order of the columns is.

Comment: Somewhat a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629521/datagridview-column-order-does-not-seem-to-work