# displayindex datatable/dgv columns not working

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, columnsorting

I set up some datatables via the Visual Studio table/columns collection editor. Sadly, it appears MS didn't include any way to re-order the data columns in the collection editor once you've done (no up/down facility). Thus, I'm having to programmatically re-order my columns (as out of order in the collection).

Done a lot of reading on this and for the life of me, can't locate the source of the problem. Basically, despite the code below, the datacolumns still show out-of-order on the datagridview. Code (abridged):

```
Private Sub LoadTextStylesDGV()
    With _TextStylesDGV
        .DefaultCellStyle.Padding = New Padding(0, 5, 0, 5)
        .AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
        .AllowUserToAddRows = False
        .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
        .AllowUserToResizeColumns = True

        .Columns.Add(New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn With {.DataPropertyName = "TextAlign", .Visible = True,
                                              .Name = "TextAlign",
                                            .HeaderText = "TextAlign",
                                              .DataSource = MarqueeEditor._EnumDDContentAlign,
                                              .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat,
                                              .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells})
' And other column setups similar to above
' ....
    .DataSource = Global.CPWBAdmin.MarqueeEditor.MarqueeData.Tables("TextStyles")
        .MultiSelect = False
        .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False

        With .Columns("ID")
            .ReadOnly = True
            .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            .Visible = False
            .DisplayIndex = 0
            .Frozen = True
        End With

        With .Columns("Name")
            .DisplayIndex = 1
            .Frozen = True
            .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Linen
        End With

        .Columns("RandomStyle?").DisplayIndex = 2

        With .Columns("Font")
            .ReadOnly = True
            .DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
            .DisplayIndex = 3
        End With

'.... other column display index settings

    .Columns("Stroke3LineJoin").DisplayIndex = 49
        .Columns("Stroke3Wrap").DisplayIndex = 50
        .Columns("TextAutoFit").DisplayIndex = 51
        'Sort:
        .Sort(_TextStylesDGV.Columns("Name"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm wondering whether the DGV columns are getting re-ordered elsewhere in the code. Of course - no way to check this with step-by-step debugging as happens before form show. Have trawled through the code but can't see anything obvious. Does anyone have any ideas as this one is killing me! If only MS had allowed column collection re-ordering. :(

Answer (score 1):

Oooops. Didn't search hard enough! Finally found the solution:

```
dgvReservedStalls.AutoGenerateColumns = True
dgvReservedStalls.DataSource = clsReservedStalls.LoadDataTable()
dgvReservedStalls.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

auto generates the columns from the DT, then frees it for re-ordering the columns. A little obscure, MS... :)

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120906/3472225)