# Reordering columns of datagridview not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I save the displayed index of each column of my Datagrid before terminating to a config file.
When restarting the application, I want to restore the order the columns where before terminating.
This does not work.
Here is my code for reordering:

```
   Private Sub reorderColumns()
        'convert the list of KeyValuePairs to a dictionary for easier access
       Try
            For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In MainDGV.Columns
                column.DisplayIndex = SettingsKeeper.getInstance.positionOfColumnInGrid(column.Name)
            Next
        Catch ex As KeyNotFoundException
            'Ignore, this means the config was not good, which generally means it was not yet
            'created once
        Catch ex As Exception
            printErrorMessage(ex,ErrorCodes.Class_ReorderColumns)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

in my initialization function, I followed the advise from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629521/datagridview-column-order-does-not-seem-to-work) regarding the AutogenerateColumns attribute, but that didn't solve anything.

this is my defacto constructor, which needs to be called after initialization:

```
Public Sub init()
        dt = New DataTable
        Dim arr(CentralControl.dgvColumns.Count - 1) As String

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each att As String In CentralControl.DataTemplate.Keys
            dt.Columns.Add(att, GetType(String))
            arr(i) = "No Data"
            i += 1
        Next

        For i = 1 To SettingsKeeper.getInstance.numberRows
            dt.Rows.Add(arr)
        Next

        MainDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        MainDGV.DataSource = dt
        MainDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        reorderColumns()
    End Sub
```

my DataTemplate is in reality a dictionary that contains the name of datacolumn as key and some rules for calculating the value for this column as value of the dictionaries entry.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I will use, until I find something cleaner:
 change init function slightly:

```
Public Sub init()
    dt = New DataTable
    Dim arr(CentralControl.dgvColumns.Count - 1) As String

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each att As String In CentralControl.DataTemplate.Keys
        dt.Columns.Add(att, GetType(String))
        arr(i) = "No Data"
        i += 1
    Next

    For i = 1 To SettingsKeeper.getInstance.numberRows
        dt.Rows.Add(arr)
    Next
    MainDGV.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    MainDGV.DataSource = dt
    'changes:
    Dim sorted As New SortedDictionary(Of Integer, String)
    For Each pair In SettingsKeeper.getInstance.positionOfColumnInGrid
        sorted.Add(pair.Value, pair.Key)
    Next


    For Each col In sorted
        Dim dgvcol As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        dgvcol.HeaderText = col.Value
        dgvcol.Name = col.Value
        dgvcol.DataPropertyName = col.Value
        MainDGV.Columns.Add(dgvcol)
    Next
end sub
```